# Errno 2 No Such File or Directory on 2 splits

Tags: python

I have this code

```
import urllib.request
fw = open("myfile.txt", "r")
red = fw.read()
line = red.split("\n")
blue = line.split("@")[0]
i=0
while i<len(blue):
    try:
        try code is here
        try:
            try code is here
        except:
            print(blue[i] + " is " + "having e1")
    except:
        print(blue[i] + " is " + "having e2")

    i+=1
```

I am getting

> Errno 2 No Such File or Directory

when I try to run my file. However, when I remove the line `blue = line.split("@")` it works fine.

What I want to do is to repeat this code on all the lines of `myfile.txt` - so I split `\n` first to get one line of the file  then I want to get the characters before `@` in this line and put it in the string `blue`

I can't understand why it work when I remove `blue = line.split("@")`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line = red.split("\n") 
blue = line.split("@")[0]
```

When you do `red.split("\n")`, you obtain a list of lines. So `line` in your code is essentially a list of lines.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> red = '''\                                             
... This is line 1                                          
... This is line 2                                         
... This is line 3'''                                       
>>> red.split('\n')                                         
['This is line 1', 'This is line 2', 'This is line 3']
```

You cannot perform `split` on a list.
Instead, get each item of `line` and perform split on it.

Here is a *list-comprehension* way of dealing with the issue:

```
blue = [x.split('@')[0] for x in line]
```

In above code, we iterate through each item in `line` (which is a list of lines as already explained). In each iteration, `x` takes each value out of `line`. `x` takes one line, does split on that, then on next iteration, takes next line from list, splits and continues till end.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what is `x` ? @Austin

Comment: Please find the explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explaination! :)